# Matlab: Working on obtaining detected face using 'Detect and Track Multiple Face'

Tags: matlab, crop, face-detection, video-tracking

Currently I try to run example [Detect and Track Multiple Face](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47105-detect-and-track-multiple-faces). When I try to crop the images of detected face as follow:

```
.....
while keepRunning
.....
displayFrame = insertMarker(displayFrame, tracker.Points);
for I=1:size(bboxes,1)
    J = imcrop(displayFrame, tracker.Bboxes(I, :));
    imshow(J);
    cropfile = sprint('crop %d.jpg, I);
    imwrite(J, cropfile, 'jpg');
 end
.....
```

However when the subject is out of view, there will be an error regarding 'index is out of bounds because size(tracker.Bboxes)=[0,4].

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? You can deal with this by either nesting the incriminated code inside an `if` statement that will check the size of `tracker.Bboxes` or by nesting it inside a try/catch block and handle the error yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are no more in `frame` then  bounding box is empty ;you should check it before looping

```
if ~isempty(bboxes)
    for I=1:size(bboxes,1) 
    J = imcrop(displayFrame, tracker.Bboxes(I, :));
    imshow(J);
    cropfile = strcat('crop', num2str(I));
    cropfilefull =[cropfile,'.jpg'];
    imwrite(J, cropfilefull, 'jpg');
    end
end
```

it worked for me

Comment: thanks @vinodlahire it's working . But I have to check if ~isempty(tracker.Bboxes) instead of if ~isempty(bboxes)